# Couchbase - get doc if value of key is empty (i.e. has length 0 )

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

I have a View in Couchbase that I use to retrieve my data. Simplified, my data bucket contains:

```
{
    "id" : 123,
    "key" : "some value"
},
{
    "id" : 456,
    "key" : ""
}
...
```

and I want to get all the docs where 'key' is present, but its value is empty.

If I use a view like this:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if(doc.key)
    emit([doc.id], doc);
}
```

I get both the JSONs above, if I use a view like this:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if(doc.key && doc.key == "")
    emit([doc.id], doc);
}
```

I get none of them.
I want to get the json with id = 456. What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because empty string is false in javascript

```
~ $ node 
> var x = ""
undefined
> x
''
> if (x && x == "") { console.log("it is empty") }
undefined
> if (x) { console.log("it is empty") }
undefined
> if (!x) { console.log("it is empty") }
it is empty
undefined
```

You should use something like

```
if(doc.key === "")
```

Triple equals will compare it to string more strictly

Comment: short and funny video about WAT effects in javascript and ruby :) https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: Thank you, it worked. (I still don't understand why do I have to use `if(doc.key === "")` instead of `if(doc.key && doc.key === "")`, though. What if there is a json without that `key`?).

Comment: You can compare with `undefined`. Like `var doc = {x: ""}; doc.y == undefined` yields `true`, and `doc.x == undefined` gives you `false`